# convert pickle (.pck) file into spark data frame using python

Tags: apache-spark, bigdl

**Hello!**
Dear members i want to train model using Bigdl, i have data set of Medical images in the form of pickle object files (,pck).that pickle file is a 3D image(3D array)

i have tried to convert this into spark datafram by using BigDl python API

```
 pickleRdd = sc.pickleFilehome/student/BigDL- 
 trainings/elephantscale/data/volumetric_data/329637-8.pck
 sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
 df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(pickleRdd)
```

it throws error

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2, localhost, executor driver)
: java.io.IOException: file:/home/student/BigDL-trainings/elephantscale/data/volumetric_data/329637-8.pck not a SequenceFile
```

*i have executed this code on python 3.5 as well as 2.7 in both cases i am getting  error*